# Javascript ES6 on Nodejs : TypeError: object is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have this sample class **sync.js** as a module somewhere on my project.

```
'use strict';

export default class Sync{

    constructor(dbConnection){
        this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
    }

    test(){
        return "This is a test " + this.dbConnection;
    }
}
```

Then somewhere on my controller I am using this class as :

```
'use strict';

import Sync from '../../path/to/module'; // <-- works fine

const sync = new Sync('CONNECTION!'); // <-- meh

console.log(sync.test());
```

I was expecting something like this to be logged on the console `This is a test CONNECTION!`. But instead I am getting this error. `TypeError: object is not a constructor`

What did I do wrong?

By the way if I removed the line `const sync = new Sync('CONNECTION!');` and changed `console.log()` to `console.log(Sync.test());` the output `This is a test undefined` is printed which is kind of what I expected. But what's wrong with my instatiation?

**WTF?**

**Edit**

Guys I think I found the problem, based on [@JLRishe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945651/jlrishe) and [rem035](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3928341/nem035) pointed out, it was returning the instance of the class not the class itself. In fact there is an `index.js` that imports the `'./sync'` js file and exporting is as `export default new Sync();`. Here's the whole `index.js`.

```
'use strict';

import Sync from './sync';

export default new Sync(); // <-- potential prodigal code
```

The module tree looks like this.

```
module
  |
  |_ lib
  |  |_ index.js // this is the index.js I am talking about
  |  |_ sync.js
  |
  |_ index.js // the entry point, contains just `module.exports = require('./lib');`
```

Now. How do I export `export default new Sync();` without doing `new`?

Comment: This works for fine for me

Comment: WTH? Really? @nem035 that's weird. :(

Comment: Looks fine (although the `'use strict'` is superfluous). Are you sure the path is right? What does `console.log(Sync)` give?

Comment: @Bergi well I commented out the instantiation and the output of `console.log(Sync)` is `Sync { dbConnection: undefined }`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `new` accidentally in your default export? The code you've shown us does export the class, not an instance.

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx It seems pretty clear your `Sync` variable is an _instance_ of the `Sync` class rather than the class itself. Couldn't say why though. Are you showing us the full contents, unmodified, of your sync.js file?

Comment: @Bergi I see, that was the whole class code though.

Comment: @JLRishe ooh. So how do I import the class itself? :/

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx But was it the whole module code? Are you sure you're not doing `Sync = new Sync` somewhere in there?

Comment: @Bergi please read update :)

Comment: @JLRishe please read update :)

Comment: I posted an answer you can try, i'm wondering don't you get error in your constructor because this.dbConnection does not exist??

Comment: @JorawarSingh I saw your answer, thanks, but unfortunately I dont think it will help. But thank you so much for reading my question. :)

Comment: posts about classes that are really about import issues need to be retitled to keep stackoverflow navigable. Hopefully someone reads this and takes my input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

> How do I export export default new Sync(); without doing new?

Just remove the `new` keyword from `module/lib/index.js`:

```
import Sync from './sync';

export default Sync;
```

Or directly import from `module/lib/sync.js`

---

**EDIT 1**

Based on the what you are saying is logged,

```
Sync { dbConnection: undefined }
```

it seems like your import is returning an instance of the class (which is an object), rather than the class definition itself.

So `console.log(new Sync())` would return what you are saying,

```js
class Sync {

  constructor(dbConnection) {
    this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
  }

  test() {
    return "This is a test " + this.dbConnection;
  }
}

console.log(new Sync());
```

not `console.log(Sync)`

```js
class Sync {

  constructor(dbConnection) {
    this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
  }

  test() {
    return "This is a test " + this.dbConnection;
  }
}

console.log(Sync);
```

Are you sure you aren't calling `new Sync` anywhere prior to exporting?

---

**Initial answer**

The code in question works fine:

```js
'use strict';

class Sync {

  constructor(dbConnection) {
    this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
  }

  test() {
    return "This is a test " + this.dbConnection;
  }
}

const sync = new Sync('CONNECTION!');

console.log(sync.test());
```

Based on your error:

```
TypeError: object is not a constructor
```

Your `import` is not returning what you think it's returning and you are trying to `new` something that cannot be instantiated.

Most likely your `import` path is wrong.

Comment: Weird but `import` has returned the class, I tried printing it and the output is `Sync { dbConnection: undefined }` is this right?

Comment: No, that looks like an object. Logging a class should give a function block as a string (in Chrome): `function class Sync {

  constructor(dbConnection) {
    this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
  }

  test() {
    return "This is a test " + this.dbConnection;
  }
}`

Comment: I thought so, but the fact the the log is printing something isn't it enough proof that the path is correct?

Comment: Based on the log, It seems like your `import` is returning an instance of the class (which is an object), rather than the class definition itself. So `console.log(new Sync())` would return what you are saying, not `console.log(Sync)`

Comment: Yo! Did that a while ago, but now `console.log(Sync)` prints `undefined`. :/

Comment: As you can see, I've debugged 3 potential issues you might have had and I don't have enough information and honestly no motivation to continue :). You should think about where you are logging `undefined`, in which file, put a breakpoint there and start debugging backwards until you find the place where the bug is happening.

Comment: importing it directly from the path doesn't seem to work as well. Damn it. Hey thanks a lot bro! This help me a lot. :)

Comment: "Daily vote limit reached;" LOL! gonna upvote this after 4 hours :)

Comment: Actually... `export default Sync;` worked! But does nodejs caching the changes? Coz it doesn't seem to apply immediately. :/ I have to re-run the code a few times before it fired correctly. :/

Answer (score 4):

Since this is the top result on google:

If you are using `require()` statements in Node to import classes and introduce a circular dependency, you will suddenly see this error popping up because `require()` is returning `{}` instead of the class.

Comment: Yes, this is often just a circular dependency in Node